# forecast.io format for tasker

Tags: tasker, weather

I am trying to get hourly precipitation probability from forecast.io 's api.  I am very beginner with tasker, without any idea of JSON.
So as given in the first profile of the blog http://blog.artesea.co.uk/2014/06/one-line-weather-summary.html,  I have changed the info.minutely.summery to precipProbability.hourly.data,  which is not working.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close on the syntax, but there's an error based upon the .api's structure.  Instead of  `precipProbability.hourly.data`, you'll need to use `hourly.data[0].precipProbability`.  Replace the [0] with any value between 0-48 for the number of hours into the future you want the data.

Also,it's helpful to get a json viewer to help interpret the structure for selecting the correct values.  I use [json viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.borzaindustries.jsondroid) which allows you to enter your forecast.io api call direct and see your data live.  You can also use the timemachine functionality and test your parsing against different weather conditions (e.g. severe weather alerts).